# Syntax and logic for moving player around game board array using do while loop java programming

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, logic, do-while

I am trying to make a player move around a 2d board array in java while utilizing accessor and mutator methods to update the attributes of my object so I am going to try and make this question as in depth as possible.  I do not understand the logic or the syntax that I must use to properly move the player and return the required information.  I am working from code that was developed.  My job is to move the player around the board and return information from a monopoly text file including the player position and new bank balance.  Additionally, I have to ask if the player wants to continue and stop the game if the bank balance is zero. I really need help with the do while loop in the main method.  I cannot get the syntax correct and do not have a great understanding of how the logic works. I am posting all of my code thus far.

```
package monopoly;

import java.util.*;

public class Monopoly {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BoardSquare[] square = new BoardSquare[40]; // array of 40 monopoly squares


    Player thePlayer = new Player();//new object thePlayer from Player class
    thePlayer.getLocation();//call method getLocation which should be instantiated from player class to zero
    int i;
    loadArray(square);

    Dice diceOne = new Dice();//new dice object
    Dice diceTwo = new Dice();//new dice object
    int rollOne;    //variable to hold rollOne
    int rollTwo;    //variable to hold rollTwo
    int rollTotal;  //variable to hold rollTotal

        do {

            rollOne = diceOne.roll();
            rollTwo = diceTwo.roll();
            rollTotal = rollOne+rollTwo;

            BoardSquare newPosition = square[thePlayer.getLocation() + rollTotal];
        } 

        while (thePlayer.getBalance() > 0);

        // test the code by printing the data for each square

        System.out.println("Data from the array of Monopoly board squares. Each line has:\n");

        System.out.println("name of the square, type, rent, price, color\n");

        for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)

        System.out.println( square[i].toString() );     
}

//**************************************************************

// method to load the BoardSquare array from a data file
public static void loadArray(BoardSquare[] square) throws Exception {

    int i; // a loop counter

    // declare temporary variables to hold BoardSquare properties read from a file
    String inName;    
    String inType;
    int inPrice;
    int inRent;
    String inColor;

    // Create a File class object linked to the name of the file to be read
    java.io.File squareFile = new java.io.File("squares.txt");

    // Create a Scanner named infile to read the input stream from the file
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(squareFile);


    /* 
     * This loop reads data into the square array.
     * Each item of data is a separate line in the file.
     * There are 40 sets of data for the 40 squares.
     */

    for(i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

        // read data from the file into temporary variables
        // read Strings directly; parse integers
        inName  = infile.nextLine(); 
        inType  = infile.nextLine(); 
        inPrice = Integer.parseInt( infile.nextLine() );
        inRent  = Integer.parseInt( infile.nextLine() );;
        inColor = infile.nextLine(); 

        // intialze each square with the BoardSquare constructor
        square[i] = new BoardSquare(inName, inType, inPrice, inRent, inColor);
    } // end for

    infile.close();

}    // endLoadArray

}    // end class Monopoly

//**************************************************************

class BoardSquare {

private String name;    // the name of the square
private String type;    // property, railroad, utility, plain, tax, or  toJail 
private int price;      // cost to buy the square; zero means not for sale
private int rent;       // rent paid by a player who lands on the square 
private String color;   // many are null; this is not the Java Color class

// constructors
public BoardSquare() {
    name = "";
    type = "";
    price = 0;
    rent = 0;
    color = "";
} // end Square()

public BoardSquare(String name, String type, int price, int rent, String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
    this.rent = rent;
    this.color = color;
} // end Square((String name, String type, int price, int rent, String color)

// accesors for each property
public String getName() {
    return name;
}   //end getName()

public String getType() {
    return type;
}   //end  getType()

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}   //end  getPrice()

public int getRent() {
    return rent;
}   //end  getRent()

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}   //end  getColor()

// a method to return the BoardSquare's data as a String
public String toString() {
    String info;
    info = (name +", "+type+", "+price + ", "+ rent+ ", "+color);
    return info;    
}   //end  toString()

} // end class BoardSquare

//**************************************************************

class Player {
    private String name;
    private String token;
    private int location;
    private int balance;
    private String player;

    public Player() {
        name = "";
        token = "";
        location = 0;
        balance = 1500;
} // end Square()

    public Player(String name, String token, int location, int balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.token = token;
        this.location = location;
        this.balance = balance;       
    }    

/*
 * @return the name
 */

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the token
 */

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

/**
 * @param token the token to set
 */

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

/**
 * @return the location
 */

public int getLocation() {
    return location;
}

/**
 * @param location the location to set
 */

public void setLocation(int location) {
    this.location = location;
}

/**
 * @return the balance
 */

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

/**
 * @param balance the balance to set
 */

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

/**
 * @return the player
 */

public String getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

/**
 * @param player the player to set
 */

public void setPlayer(String player) {
    this.player = player;
}

void setLocation() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

} //end class player

//**************************************************************

class Dice {

    public static int roll() {
        int total;
        total = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 6);

        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit and include output. and point to the wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with writting down what should happen in the loop. I suggest some of the follwing:

- print state of the board
- throw dices and move player
- perform action on new square (i.e ask player whether he wants to buy it or take the money if thesquare belongs to somebody else)
- go too top, but now with the next player

You best write functions for all these steps. And as said, you'll probably want more than one player instance.

**Edit:**

Syntactically, you've almost got everything there already.

This prints the current state of the board, just copy it where you need it:

```
for( i=0; i<40; i++)
System.out.println( square[i].toString() );
```

The code in the loop moves the player:

```
rollOne=diceOne.roll();
rollTwo=diceTwo.roll();
rollTotal=rollOne+rollTwo;

BoardSquare newPosition=square[thePlayer.getLocation()+rollTotal];
```

Then the only step remaining is actually to perform the operation on the target square. This should probably best be a function of the player, so that would be:

```
player.ActionOnSquare(newPosition);
```

That requires a method in the player class:

```
public void OperationOnSquare(BoardSquare newSquare)
{
     // Perform some operation, like reduce balance
}
```

Finally, you can ask the player whether he wants to continue. The mentioned steps 5 and 6 (you meant to write 6 and 7) are redundant, as that's already at the beginning of the next loop.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  The assignment actually only calls for one player for now.  I have developed the logic as follows: 1. call player object which should be initialized to zero according to get method in player class. 2. roll die 3. assign new position in array and return data 4. subtract rent from balance 5. ask player if he wants to move again 5. roll die again 6. add new position to previous position in array and return data  I am not sure how to go about developing the syntax to do this in the main method in my do while loop